# How to obtain super Saiyan

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I'm trying to obtain or buy super Saiyan, but I don't know how I can obtain it. My character is a Saiyan level 20+/- and I just finish Cell.

It isn't in the store, also I didn't obtain it in any mission.

Does anyone know how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Super Saiyan transformation ultimate for free by completing all of the bonus objectives in PQ15 *The Legendary Super Saiyan* (3-star difficulty), however it's quite a random drop chance and Goku doesn't always turn Super Saiyan even if you meet all of the criteria.  It will also be difficult at your level (I went from 23 to 37 just doing that PQ before it finally dropped for me).

If you don't feel like grinding for it, it'll be available in the Skill Shop after you complete the Android Saga (which is the next one up after the Cell Saga, oddly) in the main quest line.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/208246/83262

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you fight the Androids AFTER you fight cell, as opposed to Before them as it occurs in the Anime (and possibly the manga)?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Weirdly, yes. It doesn't really make sense to me either, but for whatever reason that's how they've decided to order those particular sagas.

Comment: Probably because you are timetraveling and the bad guys try the stronger first? who knows

Comment: @xerido All of the other Sagas appear in order - it's just these two that have been swapped around

Comment: ok, thanks, probably i wait until complete the Android saga, because i tried to obtain it throw PQ15 ( 3 times) and all of them i obtained B, and obviously doesn't drop the Super Saiyan. Thanks.

Comment: Getting Super Saiyan is just crazy, I managed to get SS2 first.